# How can I 'require' a Perl library addressed by a path returned by a subroutine?

Tags: perl

I can use this to include a file `a.pl`:

```
require 'a.pl';
```

Or I can use this:

```
$fn = 'a.pl';
require $fn;
```

However, a subroutine won't work:

```
sub fn { return 'a.pl'; }
require fn(); # This is a syntax error
```

Is there a syntax for allowing this? I noticed that I can work around the issue via

```
sub fn { return 'a.pl'; }
require eval("fn()");
```

...but that's not terribly pretty.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
require(fn());
```

What a curious syntax error! Adding an extra parenthesis to disambiguate precedence fixes the problem. It seems that otherwise the `require PACKAGE` form would have precedence over `require EXPR`, i.e. the `fn` is parsed as the bareword designating the module you want to load.

Comment: or you could add a & :)

Comment: Oh, I didn't think of that! Yes, anything that prevents a bareword token directly after `require` works (except unary `+`, for some reason?). But let's rather stick to Modern Perl, and never speak of `&foo()` style calls again :D

Comment: `+` works, but with a warning since you could have meant `require() +foo()`

Answer (score 0):

The following may appear "modern" but not sufficiently correct/standard/[POLA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_astonishment):

`require fn->();`

Or maybe an anonymous subroutine is more readable/efficient in some way:

```
my $fn = sub { return "a.pl"; } ;
require $fn->();
```